# English constraint free grammar prolog

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop, dcg, left-recursion, failure-slice

I ran into an infinite recursion problem while trying to implement a very simple constraint free grammar in prolog.

Here are my rules: (vp -> verb phrase, np -> noun phrase, ap -> adj phrase, pp -> prep phrase)

```
    verb(S) :- member(S, [put,  pickup, stack, unstack]).
    det(S) :- member(S, [the]).
    adj(S) :- member(S, [big, small, green, red, yellow, blue]).
    noun(S) :- member(S, [block, table]).
    prep(S) :- member(S, [on, from]).

    vp([V|R]) :- verb(V), pp(PP), np(NP), append(NP, PP, R).
    np([D, N]) :- det(D), noun(N).
    np([D|R]) :- det(D), ap(AP), noun(N), append(AP, [N], R).
    ap([A]) :- adj(A).
    ap([A|R]) :- adj(A), ap(R).
    pp([P|R]) :- prep(P), np(R).
```

The problem im running into is that the rule for **ap** can produce arbitrarily long strings of adjectives, so at some point, i get stuck trying to satisfy the query by trying all these infinite possibilities.

For example, the following query will never produce S = [put, the, red, block, on, the, green, block] because it will first expand the adjective phrase on the left "red" to infinite possibilities before ever trying on the right.

```
?- vp(S)
S = [put, the, red, green, block, on, the, block] ;
```

Comment: I think you mean context-free grammar.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: Use Definite Clause Grammars ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)) to represent your grammar.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399774/prolog-recursion-grammar/10401614#10401614) for a typical encoding.

But now to your actual problem in your program. Not only will you not get the desired answer ; the situation is worse: even in a much simpler fragment of your program will you have the very same problems.  Here is the smallest fragment of your program that still does not terminate:

```
verb(S) :- member(S, [put,  pickup, stack, unstack]).
det(S) :- member(S, [the]).
adj(S) :- member(S, [big, small, green, red, yellow, blue]).
noun(S) :- false, member(S, [block, table]).
prep(S) :- member(S, [on, from]).

vp([V|R]) :- verb(V), pp(PP), false, np(NP), append(NP, PP, R).
np([D, N]) :- false, det(D), noun(N).
np([D|R]) :- det(D), ap(AP), false, noun(N), append(AP, [N], R).
ap([A]) :- false, adj(A).
ap([A|R]) :- adj(A), ap(R), false.
pp([P|R]) :- prep(P), np(R), false.

?- vp([put, the, red, green, block, on, the, block]).
```

By inserting goals **`false`** we got a small fragment of your program that still does not terminate.
The actual source is `ap/1` which is recursive but not limited by the actual input. See [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) for more examples.

There is no easy way out to fix your program. The easiest way out is to use grammars.

Comment: @DanielLyons: That is the very idea of failure-slices: You have to change **something** in the visible part. The strike-through part is irrelevant.

Comment: @DanieLyons: You are confusing termination with the accidental finding of an answer. Yes, *sometimes* you get answers. But you cannot predict easily when. Also adding `vp(_).` as a fact on top will do it...

Comment: @DanielLyons: The **entire** failure-slice is the reason why the program does not terminate. And please recall that both Prolog and DCGs were developed to precisely address this problem.

Comment: Having gone back I see now that I misread the OP's question. I apologize for the flamewar.

Comment: @DanielLyons: That's fine! Did you remove your own comments? (I did not flag them; found them ok). But in any case: I think you could profit a lot from the notion of failure-slice behind.

Comment: I did, they're unnecessary clutter. I would like to know more about failure slices (that you're so keen on them is actually a pretty strong incentive). I keep meaning to sit down with O'Keefe's book and dig through them and the references you have.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139640/prolog-successor-notation-yields-incomplete-result-and-infinite-loop/10141181#10141181 contains a reference too. I am not sure what you mean by unnecessary clutter. With a failure-slice you can narrow down the size of your program to a source of non-termination.

Comment: I meant my comments were clutter.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're are abusing of Prolog generative power, placing append at last position. I tried to change to a more sensible place:

```
...
vp([V|R]) :- verb(V), append(NP, PP, R), pp(PP), np(NP).
np([D, N]) :- det(D), noun(N).
np([D|R]) :- det(D), append(AP, [N], R), ap(AP), noun(N).
...
```

and now your parser apparently works.

```
?- vp([put, the, red, green, block, on, the, block]).
true .
```

but I suggest, as already false did (+1), to switch to DCG for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that Prolog is defined to do a DFS over rules, so when it comes to generation problems across an infinite search space (as with your case), parts of the space can get untouched.  A platform-independent fix is to augment the grammar with a depth bound, and decrement the depth at each recursive call.  Once the depth reaches 0, fail.  By incrementally increasing the depth with repeated queries (e.g., `vp(S, 1). vp(S, 2).`), you guarantee that all parts of the state space will get touched eventually.

This is basically just iterative deepening.  If you're on SWI-PL, you can also use the [`call_with_depth_limit/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=call_with_depth_limit/3) predicate to do the exact same thing without modifying the grammar.

Comment: This question was about grammars, where the input list may be used to limit the search space considerably - often down to the minimal linear case. Iterative deepening is fine in general but applied naively leads to forbidding overheads.