# Prolog - Finding alternative words (synonyms)

Tags: list, dictionary, prolog, predicate, synonym

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about creating a synonym finder in Prolog.

---

I have some words here...

```
word(likes).
word(house).
word(chair).
```

If the input was likes, I would want to output a synonym such as 'loves'. Or for house I would want to output 'home'.

I want to do this with the synonym predicate instead of adding the alternative words as a new word().

I've got as far as doing this:

```
synonym (house,[home]).
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What you want is [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/), which is conveniently available as a Prolog database.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to enumerate your cases manually I would consider having a predicate that "normalizes" or "simplifies" vocabulary. For instance, something like this:

```
%% synonym(Synonym, CanonicalTerm) :- Synonym is a synonym for CanonicalTerm
synonym(loves,  enjoys).
synonym(likes,  enjoys).
synonym(enjoys, enjoys).
```

Prologs usually index on the first argument, so this lookup will be fast (certainly faster than enumerating the whole database and doing a `member/2` lookup). And then you can simply perform this step after parsing or on-demand, and code your rules around the canonical term.

WordNet probably does not consider `love` and `like` to be synonyms, really, so it is probably overkill for your needs.

Let's apply this to the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703388/sentence-parsing-and-matching-in-prolog):

```
?- phrase(sentence(np(Noun,_), vp(Verb, np(Object, _))),
   [a,teenage,boy,loves,a,big,problem]), 
   synonym(Verb, CanonicalVerb),
   present(Suggestion, Noun, CanonicalVerb, Object).
Noun = boy,
Verb = loves,
CanonicalVerb = enjoys,
Object = problem,
Suggestion = 'construction kit'
```

This of course assumes you update the `present/4` fact as well.