# Prolog: a list of characters <=> list of character list

Tags: list, prolog, char

I am implementing a `words/2` predicate in which a list of characters can be rendered to a list of the character as a word inside a list. I use the mathematical symbol `<=>` to denote that they're working in any mode. Please advise if there's a better expression.

The example:

```
?- words([p,r,o,l,o,g,' ',i,s,' ',g,o,o,d],Y).
Y = [[p,r,o,l,o,g],[i,s],[g,o,o,d]]

?- words(X,[[p,r,o,l,o,g],[i,s],[g,o,o,d]]).
X = [p,r,o,l,o,g,' ',i,s,' ',g,o,o,d]
```

What I've done is trying to use `append/3` as below, trying to put the empty string in between, and concatenate them together. And recurse the `List` with `NewCharList`, but failed with "out of local stack".

```
% base case, empty list
words([],[]).
% X is a list of characters
% Y is a list with characters list as a word
words(CharList,[WordList|List]):-
    append(WordList,[' '],NewWord),
    append(NewWord,CharList,NewCharList),
    words(NewCharList,List).
```

How could I improve the code? Thanks.

**Edit1**
Million thanks from @rajashekar. Now I understand the code

```
% base case
split(_, [], [[]]).

% when the the element list of Ys is empty
% add a C to the Xs, in this case, C is a empty string ' '
split(C, [C|Xs], [[]|Ys]) :-
    split(C, Xs, Ys).

% put the X character from [X|Y] list to Xs
% and goes on next word list
split(C, [X|Xs], [[X|Y]|Ys]) :-
    split(C, Xs, [Y|Ys]).
```

but in my SWI-prolog, it seems weird that:

```
?-split(' ', X, [[p,r,o,l,o,g],[i,s],[g,o,o,d]]).
X = [p, r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s|...]
```

Here is the trace record:

```
[trace]  ?- split(X, [[p,r,o,l,o,g],[i,s],[g,o,o,d]]).
   Call: (10) split(_5702, [[p, r, o, l, o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (11) split(_6210, [[r, o, l, o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (12) split(_6266, [[o, l, o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (13) split(_6322, [[l, o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (14) split(_6378, [[o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (15) split(_6434, [[g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (16) split(_6490, [[], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (17) split(_6546, [[i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (18) split(_6596, [[s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (19) split(_6652, [[], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (20) split(_6708, [[g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (21) split(_6758, [[o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (22) split(_6814, [[o, d]]) ? creep
   Call: (23) split(_6870, [[d]]) ? creep
   Call: (24) split(_6926, [[]]) ? creep
   Exit: (24) split([], [[]]) ? creep
   Exit: (23) split([d], [[d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (22) split([o, d], [[o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (21) split([o, o, d], [[o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (20) split([g, o, o, d], [[g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (19) split([' ', g, o, o, d], [[], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (18) split([s, ' ', g, o, o, d], [[s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (17) split([i, s, ' ', g, o, o, d], [[i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (16) split([' ', i, s, ' ', g, o, o, d], [[], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (15) split([g, ' ', i, s, ' ', g, o, o|...], [[g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (14) split([o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', g, o|...], [[o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (13) split([l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' ', g|...], [[l, o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (12) split([o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s, ' '|...], [[o, l, o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) split([r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s|...], [[r, o, l, o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) split([p, r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i|...], [[p, r, o, l, o, g], [i, s], [g, o, o, d]]) ? creep
X = [p, r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s|...] .
```

**EDIT2**
I found out that using `!` (cut) could cut down the backtracking.

```
% base case
split(_, [], [[]]).

% when the the element list of Ys is empty
% add a C to the Xs, in this case, C is a empty string ' '
split(C, [C|Xs], [[]|Ys]) :-
    split(C, Xs, Ys),!.

% put the X character from [X|Y] list to Xs
% and goes on next word list
split(C, [X|Xs], [[X|Y]|Ys]) :-
    split(C, Xs, [Y|Ys]),!.
```

Comment: Use [tag:dcg]-notation!

Comment: @false Thank you for the suggestion. I've found an example of DCG such as `sentence(s(S,V,O)) --> subject(S), verb(V), object(O).` from https://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_dcg.htm . How could I express the mode that mathematically in this example that subject, verb, and object can also form a sentence, in which the relation is bidirectional?

Comment: [Consider this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10401614/772868).

Comment: Press `w` key to make SWI show the complete answer

Comment: @gusbro Thanks! It works. But since there's a testing case for the implementation, I can only write the predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
split(_, [], [[]]).
split(C, [C|Xs], [[]|Ys]) :-
    split(C, Xs, Ys).
split(C, [X|Xs], [[X|Y]|Ys]) :-
    split(C, Xs, [Y|Ys]).
```

```
| ?- split(' ', [p,r,o,l,o,g,' ',i,s,' ',g,o,o,d], X).

X = [[p,r,o,l,o,g],[i,s],[g,o,o,d]] ? 

yes
| ?- split(' ', X, [[p,r,o,l,o,g],[i,s],[g,o,o,d]]).

X = [p,r,o,l,o,g,' ',i,s,' ',g,o,o,d] ? 

yes
```

- you can use mode declaration to say the predicate works in both modes. e.g., you could have said the `words/2` predicate needs to work in both `words(+Chars, -Words)` and `words(-Chars, +Words)` modes(or in `words(+, -)` and `words(-, +)` modes). [See](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes) for mode details. These are mostly used for documentation purposes in prolog (check out [mercury](https://mercurylang.org/) where they really work).
- Using `Definite Clause Grammers` DCGs will make problems like this a whole lot easier.
- Try using `trace` when you feel a run away recursion. You can spot the problem most of the time if you use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and other suggestions, but as you can see, the requirement is using only two arguments.

Comment: And, regarding mode, in the question that both arguments could be generated, so based on the manual, it should be `words(?,?)`? Thanks.

Comment: I used `C` as an extra argument for a more general solution. You can remove it and just replace `C` with `' '` in the body of the clauses. Or just say `words(X, Y) :- split(' ', X, Y).`.  A predicate can have more than one mode, you can just document the ones you need and can guarantee the correctness. For e.g., you can say `length` works in `length(+, +)`, `length(+, -)`, `length(?, +)` and `length(?, -)` modes, but it is generally documented as just `length(?, ?)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation.

Comment: I did a test, but it seems not working. Could you please have a look? I've edited the post. Thanks, again.

Comment: @Woden: `SWI-Prolog` is eliding your solution. When the lists get too big `swipl` doesn't print all of the list by default. You can do `write(X)` to explicitly print it or press `w` at a choice point or in trace to change the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

The code does exactly what you want.
Here:

```
?-split(' ', X, [[p,r,o,l,o,g],[i,s],[g,o,o,d]]).
X = [p, r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s|...]
```

X is exactly the expected output.

If you want to see all of X, do:

```
?-split(' ', X, [[p,r,o,l,o,g],[i,s],[g,o,o,d]]), write_canonical(X).
[p,r,o,l,o,g,' ',i,s,' ',g,o,o,d]
X = [p, r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s|...]
```

Long lists are shortened on the output in SWI prolog.

Comment: Thanks for another solution, but since there's a testing case, what I can do is only writing the predicate.

Comment: The abbreviation of `X = [p, r, o, l, o, g, ' ', i, s|...]` is only visual. Internally SWI knows that X is unified with `[p,r,o,l,o,g,' ',i,s,' ',g,o,o,d]`